# How to structure translation files in SPA the best way?

Tags: localization, internationalization, frontend, single-page-application

So my question includes two parts:

1. Should I hold my translations files on the top of my app structure or should I hold a separate translation file near each component to make them really independent? How to organize it the best way?
2. What's the best approach to organize translation strings inside translation file (JSON) to avoid search and duplication issues?

Comment: The context of the question is undefined. A well-known example to organize translation tokens is the Angular [`ngx-translate`](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) module. A few tools are available for edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what frontend framework you are using, there are multiple choices:

- React - [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/)
- Angular - [Transloco](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/)

The execution in both is similar. Essentially, you either create one translation JSON file the will get loaded to the client at runtime and used for translation of keys.

Or if you prefer you can create multiple translation files, say each for a large component or module to make things more clean and separated.